# How this snippet of code is working?

Tags: javascript

```
var a = Ajax();
function st() 
    { 
        if (a.readyState==4)
        { 
        document.getElementById('acv').innerHTML=a.responseText;
        }
    }
function update() {

    url='ball.php';
    mango = document.getElementById("mango_input").value;
    orange = document.getElementById("orange_input").value;




    var q = "?mango=" + mango + "&orange=" + orange  + ; // line in question

    a.onreadystatechange=st;
    a.open("GET",url + q,true);
    a.send(null);
    }
```

Can someone please explain me the snippet of the code or else just tell me what exactly is var q doing.

Comment: `var q` is the GET parameters being put onto the urls querystring

Comment: The right side of the equal (=) sign is performing a string concatenation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

var `q` is used to concatenate all the data parameters that is to be sent in ajax request on `url='ball.php'`

`?` is used to separate these parameters from URL

```
var q = "?mango=" + mango + "&orange=" + orange + ;
a.onreadystatechange=st;
a.open("GET",url + q,true);
```

If you don't want to use any variable like `q` then you can do something like this

```
a.onreadystatechange=st;
a.open("GET",url+"?mango="+mango+"&orange="+orange, true);
```

you can directly pass parameters with URL